# glow effect with ShapeRenderer (libgdx)

Tags: libgdx, blur, glow

I read about glow/particle effecta with sprites, which are working well.

Is there a simple way to create the similar blur effect with simple shaperender functionality like circles ?

```
@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
    batch.end();
    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Point);
    shapeRenderer.setAutoShapeType(true);
    drawCircle();
    shapeRenderer.end();
    batch.begin();
}

private void drawCircle() {
    shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    shapeRenderer.set(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
    // apply effect ??
    shapeRenderer.circle(10,10,2);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to do this so you can make arbitrary shapes glow? A prerendered glow sprite will be way more performant and easier way to get a glowing circle. To do it with arbitrary ShapeRenderer shapes, you could draw to a FrameBuffer and do some blur post processing. Not trivial, but there are libraries that can make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use textures with default ShapeRender.

There are several way to do this but the easiest is to use ShapeDrawer library. It adds some "ShapeRenderer like" capabilities to a SpriteBatch and more. see https://github.com/earlygrey/shapedrawer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could create a "glow" effect, this could be achieved by drawing using decreasing alpha values past the boundaries.

Firstly, to define the glow-effect parameters, let's determine the maximum boundary of the glowing object, where the glow ends, as being `auraSize` for the size of the aura.

Next, we need to know the size of the solid portion of the object, the bit that doesn't glow, and let's call this `objSize` for the size of the object.

To draw this, we can use a simple `for` loop and some `if` statements:

```
private void drawCircle() {
    shapeRenderer.set(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);

    //Draw circles upto the size of aura
    for(int radius = 0; radius < auraSize; radius++) {
        /*
        * Checks if radius fits object size, sets colour to solid white if so
        * Interpolates alpha value to 0 based on distance to aura covered by radius otherwise
        */
        if(radius <= objSize) {
            shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        } else {
            shapeRenderer.setColor(new Color(1, 1, 1,
                     MathUtils.lerp(1, 0, (radius - objSize) / (auraSize / objSize))));
        }

        //Draws the circle at the current radius
        shapeRenderer.circle(10, 10, radius);
    }
}
```